# Jenkins Shared Library Pipelines: Singletons vs On-Demand Singletons

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In the Jenkins documentation, it mentions that all var definitions are on-demand singletons, but does not explain what that means. Documentation reference:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables

**Does this mean that the singleton is determined at the moment the job is called and so its a unique instance for that particular job? And how does this compare to an explicit @Singleton call when placed on a class?**

I tried setting up my shared pipeline so I could review both sides of it.  When I run the code below, I can see in the output that both classes print out the information I expect.  They both start as *empty strings* and then are set equal to the env.BUILD_TAG [(list of supported env variables here)](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

**My concern is that if I have multiple jobs running concurrently, do they share the same Singleton or is it unique to each build?  So far I have not been able to prove this, so I was hoping someone has an answer to this.**

**Structure**

```
src
  - org
   - utilities
     - GlobalStateClass.groovy
vars
  - globalStateVar.groovy
  - main.groovy
```

**GlobalStateClass.groovy**

```
#!groovy
package org.utilities

@Singleton
class GlobalStateClass implements Serialization{
  public String version = ""
}
```

**globalStateVar.groovy**

```
#!groovy
class globalStateVar implements Serialization{
  public String version = ""
}
```

**main.groovy**

```
#!groovy
import org.utilities.GlobalStateClass

def call () {
  println "Old Values: ${ GlobalStateClass.instance.version } ${ globalStateVar.version }"
  String v = env.BUILD_TAG
  GlobalState.instance.version = v
  globalStateVar.version = v
  println "New Values: ${ GlobalStateClass.instance.version } ${ globalStateVar.version }"
}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('test 0'){
      main()
    }
    stage('test 1'){
      main()
    }
    stage('test 2'){
      main()
    }
    stage('test 3'){
      main()
    }
  }
}
```